# ⨯ PrismaClientInitializationError: Invalid `prisma.user.findMany()` invocation:

Tags: mongodb, prism, next.js13

```
Error: 
Invalid `prisma.user.findMany()` invocation:

Error in connector: Error creating a database connection. (Kind: An error occurred during DNS resolution: proto error: io error: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. (os error 10051), labels: {})
    at Cn.handleRequestError (C:\Users\kethmark\healthmanagement\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:123:7090)
    at Cn.handleAndLogRequestError (C:\Users\kethmark\healthmanagement\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:123:6206)
    at Cn.request (C:\Users\kethmark\healthmanagement\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:123:5926)
    at async l (C:\Users\kethmark\healthmanagement\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:128:9968)
    at async GET (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/user/route.ts:28:17)
    at async C:\Users\kethmark\healthmanagement\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:62361 {
  clientVersion: '5.4.2',
  errorCode: undefined
}
```

I tried to run `npx prisma generate` still hoping that it would fix matters, but it didn't help.